# Dousign API Connection to Production env

Tags: docusignapi

We have been certified to use the DocuSign REST API in Production.
We are using mule ESB and DocuSign connector to make a connection.

But upon trying to connect, a status code 404 with no actual reason is being returned, the error, cause returns null.

Below is the stack trace:

> Failed to configure DocuSign connector:com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: error
>   com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: error
>       at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:770) ~[docusign-esign-java-2.4.0.jar:?]
>       at com.docusign.esign.api.AuthenticationApi.login(AuthenticationApi.java:278) ~[docusign-esign-java-2.4.0.jar:?]
>       at org.mule.modules.sec3uredocusign.Sec3ureDocusignConnector.setConfig(Sec3ureDocusignConnector.java:129) ~[sec3ure-docusign-connector-1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>
> ============
>
> 018-05-16 20:49:06,872 [WrapperListener_start_runner] WARN  org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'docusign_config': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.mule.modules.sec3uredocusign.exception.DocusignException (404
>   message:error
>   cause:null
>   body:null
>   stacktrace:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@11f23675): Failed to configure DocuSign connector
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[sp

If anyone has faced the same issue, can you please let us know what might be causing the above.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code, and is it working fine with DS Demo and not working with DS Prod?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in demo. But when the change the baseURL to production url with the below one : https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}. It returns 404.

Comment: Try hitting using POSTMAN or any other rest utility tool, instead of your code. Using POSTMAN you can even check if na2 is correct or not by changing it to www or na3

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are connecting to wrong datacenter in PROD. Demo has one datacenter which is demo.docusign.net, but in PROD DocuSign currently has 4 datacenter, NA1, NA2, NA3 and EU1 (its only for Europe).

Your PROD account can be in any of these data centers, and you need to know which endpoint to hit, either

```
www.docusign.net for NA1
na2.docusign.net for NA2
na3.docusign.net for NA3
```

So, you if you are using [Legacy Auth](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) then you need to know exact datacenter to hit in API call. To overcome this issue, it is recommended to use DocuSign's [OAUTH_JWT](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) approach for authentication, and you will use account.docusign.com to know the baseURI, and DocuSign will provide you the correct data center baseURI to connect to for make envelope related API calls.

Comment: When we did the Legacy Header Authentication .                            curl -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication:{"Username": "bob@example.com","Password": "xxx","IntegratorKey": "your_key"}' \
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information .          
 Docusign returned the baseURL to be used in Production 
       https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/{accountId}/